# Need help understanding appliance ratings

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I keep coming across things like "A filament lamp rated 12 V, 1.0 A", or "a heating element rated 230V, 500W".

I think the first one is saying that a 12V potential difference across it will make a current of 1A flow through it.

Can someone please explain in detail what these (and other similar ones) mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rating of

> A filament lamp rated 12 V, 1.0 A

means that it is designed to work at a voltage of 12V, and at this voltage, it consumes 1A current.

> a heating element rated 230V, 500W

is intended similarly. It means that the element is designed to work at 230V, at which it consumes 500 W power.

These sort of specifications made no sense to me when I was a kid knowing a little bit of Physics - "*Why don't the specify the resistance directly and let us do the maths*"! But it makes sense, not all elements have fixed resistances, it is generally a non-linear I-V curve and at some designated voltage, at which the device is intended to work, they tell you the useful parameter. Please notice that e.g. [a lamp filament doesn't have a constant resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/183824/46399), and the argument generalizes.

So, in general, these specifications have the form - [(parameter value at which it is designed to work), (some useful parameter value, current or power, consumed *when the device works at the value designated at parameter 1*)].

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! The part at the end about parameters really made it much simpler to understand. When you said "consumes 1A current" does it mean that if say 10A of current is flowing in that part of the circuit, then 9A would come out? But then that would mean the components in the circuit coming after the one that consumed 1A would have only 9A of current through them, which contradicts the current being a constant 10A in that part of the circuit. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to electricity.

Comment: @user45220 - In very simple terms, "consumes 1A current" means that $R_{\rm device}$ is such that the $V/R$ = 1A. I can sense that you are new to electricity, what happens in a serial connected circuit is not a drop of current from 10A to 9A upon going past an element, but rather, a drop of voltage. In fact, the voltage dropped equals $I \times R$, and the same current follows right through. I will link to some other things to help making this point clearer for you :)

Comment: @user45220 - Please look at the first diagram [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142627/46399), and read my comment in this light :)

Comment: Wow did you read my mind? This is exactly what I'm having trouble understanding! I am reading it and it is very instructive so far.

Comment: Is the answer to that problem 14/3 ohms?

Comment: @user45220 - Yes. But we don't answer HW type questions on this site, in view of the meta policy. That's why I didn't feed that in.